# PHP Get Variable avoid to remove & in URL

Tags: php, html

`page.php?clss_type=Boys%20&%20Girls`

if I try to Echo the get variable I will automatically skip the '&' in the String

`<?PHP echo $class = $_GET['clss_type'];?>`

output:  Boys instead of Boys & Girls

Comment: What happens if you replace the "&" in question with `%26`

Answer (score 0):

By default PHP uses `&` as the variable separator in a query string.

You will need to escape that character to `%26`, or you can change PHP to use a different character as the separator using the `arg_separator.input` directive in the php.ini (https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.arg-separator.input).